# Generic Success Page in ASP.NET FORM

Tags: asp.net

could anyone please show me how to write a generic success page which displays the dyanmic success messages. e.g.

> 1. Submitted successfully.
> 2. Submitted pending for review.
> 3. Saved.
> 4. Approved ...etc.

Basically each pages willl send diffferent messages to this page and this page just renders.

Comment: You really want to have a complete page only to show the result of the last user's action? And when the user has seen the result, he can go back to the last page? Normally i would use a place somewhere on the page for this purpose(f.e. a ContentPlaceHolder in a MasterPage).
Nevertheless you could use QueryStringParameters to send the message from previous page to the result-page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a parameter to a success page so it can display the right message!

You can also set a session variable and read it from success page.